# Tomcat mapeamento de diretório externo

Tags: java, java-ee, eclipse, tomcat

Tenho um aplicativo javaEE onde uso o Tomcat 8. Nele, eu mapiei uma pasta externa para salvar as imagens que o usuário pode cadastrar em uma das telas da minha aplicação. 
Para isso, fui no arquivo server.xml do meu tomcat e fiz o mapeamento. Tudo estava funcionando bem a bastante tempo, só que ontem, acabei deletando o tomcat 8 e tive que adiciona-lo novamente. Por consequência disto, tive que refazer a configuração de mapeamento no arquivo server.xml.

Ao refazer a configuração, simplesmente o mapeamento não funciona mais. Já dei um clear nos TomCat, já dei um clear e update project no Maven, e nada.
O contexto do meu aplicativo é '/Picos' e consigo acessa-lo através de

```
localhost:8080/Picos
```

Partindo dai, na tentativa de refazer a configuração, fui no server.xml do Tomcat e adicionei`<Context docBase="C:\Picos\images" path="/images" />` dentro da tag `<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">`, e simplesmente quando coloco no browser o endereço `localhost:8080/Picos/images/1.png` (lembrando que a imagem 1.png existe dentro da pasta C:\Picos\images) recebo erro 404.

O que estou fazendo de errado, já que antes do acidente de excluir o servidor Tomcat no eclipise, tudo estava funcionando perfeitamente. Será que estou esquecendo de mais alguma configuração? Alguma dica? Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi o problema. Acho justo deixar a solução aqui, já que muitos podem acabar deixando passar despercebido. 
Quando adiciono um projeto ao mu servidor tomcat, a linha `<Context docBase="Picos" path="/Picos" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Picos"/>` é adicionada ao meu server.xml. Sendo assim, o path do context para mapear o diretorio externo tem que adicionar o path do context acima. Ficaria assim `<Context docBase="C:\Picos\images" path="/Picos/images" />` e não `<Context docBase="C:\Picos\images" path="/images" />`

Espero que ajude =)

Comment: [Não é recomendado alterar o `server.xml`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html). Essa configuração pode até funcionar para se realizar testes localmente, mas em outro contexto não deve ser aplicada. Além disso, alterar o `docBase` da aplicação inteira pode causar efeitos colaterais devastadores, já que não só as imagens, mas todos os resources da aplicação serão acessados daquele diretório. Em questão de segurança, s e um usuário enviar um JSP ao invés de uma imagem, ele vai conseguir executar qualquer código no servidor.

Comment: Então como seria a maneira correta?

Comment: Depende de como funciona sua aplicação, mas a maneira mais simples é instalar a aplicação normalmente e criar um servlet para servir as imagens.

Comment: Note que isso seria diferente caso as imagens não fossem cadastradas por um usuário externo.

Comment: O upload das imagens são feitos pelos usuários, através de um aplicativo Android